# Image map inside a FancyBox Gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I'm trying to add an image map to a fancybox gallery as shown here:

```
 http://jsfiddle.net/ffZ7B/
```

I am attempting to create an online replication of our print catalog that will allow different areas of the lightbox to be linked to different item pages on our site.

Here is the code that I'm using, which works correctly for the fancybox.  The main part I'm unsure about is where to put the code under the "JavaScript" section of the fiddle.  Thanks in advance - I'm more of a .NET guy, so JavaScript is new to me but necessary due to platform limitations.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mysite.com/catalog/lib/jquery-1.8.2.min.js">        </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mysite.com/catalog/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mysite.com/catalog/source/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.3"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://mysite.com/catalog/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.2" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://mysite.com/catalog/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.5" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdmshopping.com/catalog/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://mysite.com/catalog/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mysite.com/catalog/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mysite.com/catalog/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.5"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        /*
         *  Simple image gallery. Uses default settings
         */

        $('.fancybox')
        .attr('rel', 'gallery')
        .fancybox({padding : 0});

        /*
         *  Different effects
         */

        // Change title type, overlay closing speed
        $(".fancybox-effects-a").fancybox({
            helpers: {
                title : {
                    type : 'outside'
                },
                overlay : {
                    speedOut : 0
                }
            }
        });

        // Disable opening and closing animations, change title type
        $(".fancybox-effects-b").fancybox({
            openEffect  : 'none',
            closeEffect : 'none',

            helpers : {
                title : {
                    type : 'over'
                }
            }
        });

        // Set custom style, close if clicked, change title type and overlay color
        $(".fancybox-effects-c").fancybox({
            wrapCSS    : 'fancybox-custom',
            closeClick : true,

            openEffect : 'none',

            helpers : {
                title : {
                    type : 'inside'
                },
                overlay : {
                    css : {
                        'background' : 'rgba(238,238,238,0.85)'
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        // Remove padding, set opening and closing animations, close if clicked and disable overlay
        $(".fancybox-effects-d").fancybox({
            padding: 0,

            openEffect : 'elastic',
            openSpeed  : 150,

            closeEffect : 'elastic',
            closeSpeed  : 150,

            closeClick : true,

            helpers : {
                overlay : null
            }
        });

        /*
         *  Button helper. Disable animations, hide close button, change title type and content
         */

        $('.fancybox-buttons').fancybox({
            openEffect  : 'none',
            closeEffect : 'none',

            prevEffect : 'none',
            nextEffect : 'none',

            closeBtn  : false,

            helpers : {
                title : {
                    type : 'inside'
                },
                buttons : {}
            },

            afterLoad : function() {
                this.title = 'Image ' + (this.index + 1) + ' of ' + this.group.length + (this.title ? ' - ' + this.title : '');
            }
        });


        /*
         *  Thumbnail helper. Disable animations, hide close button, arrows and slide to next gallery item if clicked
         */

        $('.fancybox-thumbs').fancybox({
            prevEffect : 'none',
            nextEffect : 'none',

            closeBtn  : false,
            arrows    : false,
            nextClick : true,

            helpers : {
                thumbs : {
                    width  : 50,
                    height : 50
                }
            }
        });

        /*
         *  Media helper. Group items, disable animations, hide arrows, enable media and button helpers.
        */
        $('.fancybox-media')
            .attr('rel', 'media-gallery')
            .fancybox({
                openEffect : 'none',
                closeEffect : 'none',
                prevEffect : 'none',
                nextEffect : 'none',

                arrows : false,
                helpers : {
                    media : {},
                    buttons : {}
                }
            });

        /*
         *  Open manually
         */

        $("#fancybox-manual-a").click(function() {
            $.fancybox.open('http://www.mysite.com/catalog/demo/gooseberry_b.jpg');
        });

        $("#fancybox-manual-b").click(function() {
            $.fancybox.open({
                href : 'iframe.html',
                type : 'iframe',
                padding : 5
            });
        });

        $("#fancybox-manual-c").click(function() {
            $.fancybox.open([
                {
                    href : 'http://www.mysite.com/catalog/demo/gooseberry_b.jpg',
                    title : 'My title'
                }, {
                    href : '2_b.jpg',
                    title : '2nd title'
                }, {
                    href : '3_b.jpg'
                }
            ], {
                helpers : {
                    thumbs : {
                        width: 75,
                        height: 50
                    }
                }
            });
        });

    });
</script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .fancybox-custom .fancybox-skin {
            box-shadow: 0 0 50px #222;
        }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<h3>Online Catalog</h3>
<p>
<a class="fancybox" href="http://www.mysite.com/catalog/demo/gooseberry_b.jpg" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Gooseberry Patch"><img src="http://www.mysite.com/catalog/demo/gooseberry_s.jpg" alt="" /></a>
<map name="Map" id="Map">
    <area shape="poly" coords="0,0,0,328,145,328" href="www.google.com" />
                            <area shape="poly" coords="0,0,180,0,328,328,142,328" href="www.google.com" /> 
                    </map>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```